# How can I monitor my own network traffic?

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools

I wanted to know what the easiest way is of monitoring the exact URL's my browser is accessing, specifically when there's an automatic redirect which causes the browser to refresh quickly before you have a chance to see what's going on. To the best of my knowledge, this can't be accomplished through the Network tab on Chrome dev tools since that's refreshed on redirect as well.

Do I need to use Wireshark or some other traffic monitoring solution in order to see exactly what happens? For reference, I want to use this information for debugging a registration in an Azure Active Directory user flow, although I don't think that's relevant since my question is just broadly how to best monitor my own traffic.

**edit**: there's a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/771822/how-to-get-a-comprehensive-listing-of-all-urls-accessed-during-a-web-browsing-se) but the recommended solution, Fiddler, appears to only have a free trial but is a pay-to-use product. Shouldn't there just be some free command line tool that might do this? Again, only asking because I can't find a non-premium tool after googling around, so, sorry if people think my question sucks but I thought asking questions you don't know the answer to and can't answer via research is the purpose of stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that Burpsuite has a free version that can do this well by using a proxy that intercepts your traffic.